# Не могу сериализовать изображение

Tags: java, изображения, сериализация

У меня есть класс, который в себе по-мимо изображения содержит ещё много объектов, `ImageIcon` не подходит так как при вызове `getImage();` возвращает не `Image`, а какой-то `ToolkitImage`, который является приватным в дебрях `AWT`. Если удастся достать из `ImageIcon` обычное изображение или объект реализующий `Image`, буду пользоваться им. Также важно что-бы все объекты сериализовались в 1 фаил. Скопировать атрибуты `BufferedImage` и восстановить их затем не получается, половина не сереализуема тоже: ( Если есть другие варианты вроде записи через обычные байтовые потоки тоже буду не против, но только в 1 файл. Нужно как можно срОчнее!! ! `ImageIO` тоже использовать не получится, это сразу означает, что картинку надо писать в отдельный файл! Буду ОЧЕНЬ благодарен за хоть какую-то наводочку!

```
package serializableClasses;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.Externalizable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;

public class SerializedPaneWithQuestion implements Externalizable {

private SerializedVarPane[] variants;
private String question;
private BufferedImage img;
private String answer;
private int mode;

public SerializedPaneWithQuestion(SerializedVarPane[] variants,
        String question, BufferedImage img, String answer, int mode) {

    this.answer = answer;
    this.question = question;
    this.img = img;
    this.variants = variants;
    this.mode =mode;

}

public SerializedPaneWithQuestion() {}

@Override
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    out.writeInt(variants.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < variants.length;i++){
        out.writeObject(variants[i]);
    }
    out.writeObject(img);
    out.writeObject(question);
    out.writeObject(answer);
    out.writeInt(mode);
}

@Override
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int length = in.readInt();
    variants = new SerializedVarPane[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        variants[i] = (SerializedVarPane) in.readObject();
    }
    img = (BufferedImage) in.readObject();
    question = (String) in.readObject();
    answer = (String) in.readObject();
    mode = in.readInt();
}

public SerializedVarPane[] getVariants() {
    return variants;
}
public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}
public BufferedImage getImg() {
    return img;
}
public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}
public int getMode() {
    return mode;
}
public void setVariants(SerializedVarPane[] variants) {
    this.variants = variants;
}
public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}
public void setImg(BufferedImage img) {
    this.img = img;
}
public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}
public void setMode(int mode) {
    this.mode = mode;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How can I Serialize a BufferedImage](https://community.oracle.com/message/4666276)

там пишут, что можно использовать ImageIO для записи в память, а не только на диск.

Comment: Благодарен вам, но я нашел немного другое решение:
1) Сначала разбить на байты изображение с помощью ImageIO.write();
   и записать это дело в ByteArrayOutputStream, получить оттуда
   массив байт и его уже сериализовывать.
2) Затем с помощью ImageIO.read(); читаю собственно из этого массива
   создав на его основе ByteArrayInputStream
   
PROFIT:)